# ModelValidationError c# asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, exception

i'm trying to create a DB using MySql code in visual studio and after that i'm trying to add some items it. I keep getting "ModelValidationException"-errors and other errors in the past... Here's some information:

Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        Database.SetInitializer<BachelorproefContext>(new BachelorproefInitializer());
    }
```

BachelorproefContext:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class BachelorproefContext : DbContext
{
    public BachelorproefContext() : base("Bachelorproef")
    {}

    public DbSet<Gebruiker> Gebruikers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GebruikerMap());
        /*modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PromotorMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BPCoordinatorMap());*/

    }
}
```

BachelorproefInitializer:

```
    protected override void Seed(BachelorproefContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            Gebruiker stijn = new Student ("Stijn", "Raes", "stijn.raes.t9199@student.hogent.be", "123ABC%d", "209199sr", true );
            context.Gebruikers.Add(stijn);
            Gebruiker bram = new Student ( "Bram", "Dobbelaere", "bram.dobbelaere.t8490@student.hogent.be", "123ABC%d", "209199sr", true );
            context.Gebruikers.Add(bram);
            Gebruiker branko = new Student ( "Branko", "Vergaert", "branko.vergaert.s5314@student.hogent.be", "123ABC%d", "209199sr", true );
            context.Gebruikers.Add(branko);
            Gebruiker gilles = new Student ( "Gilles", "De Vylder", "gilles.devylder.t1075@student.hogent.be", "123ABC%d", "209199sr", true );
            context.Gebruikers.Add(gilles);
            Gebruiker vrekke = new BPCoordinator ( "Bert", "Vrekke", "stijn.raes.t9199@hogent.be", "123ABC%d", "123456bv", false );
            context.Gebruikers.Add(vrekke);
            Gebruiker karien = new Promotor ( "Karien", "Samyn", "stijn.raes.t9199@hogent.be", "123ABC%d", "123456ks", false );
            context.Gebruikers.Add(karien);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:", eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.GetValidationResult());
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The class Gebruiker:

```
public abstract class Gebruiker
{
    [Key]
    private string stamNummer;
    private string familienaam, voornaam, email, wachtwoord;
    private bool eersteLogin;

    public Gebruiker()
    {

    }
// other Properties & password generator
```

The class GebruikerMap:

```
public class GebruikerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Gebruiker>
{
    public GebruikerMap() {

        //Primary key
        this.HasKey(t => t.StamNummer);

        //Properties
        HasKey(k => k.StamNummer);
        this.Property(t => t.StamNummer).HasMaxLength(8).IsFixedLength();
        Property(g => g.Familienaam).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        Property(g => g.Voornaam).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        Property(g => g.Wachtwoord).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
        Property(g => g.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

        //Overerving
        this.Map<Student>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Student"));
        this.Map<BPCoordinator>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Coordinator"));
        this.Map<Promotor>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Promotor"));

        //Table
        this.ToTable("Gebruiker");
    }
}
```

An example of an inheritance class "Student" (BPCoordinator & Promotor are the same):

```
public class Student : Gebruiker
{
    public Student()
    {

    }

    public Student(string voornaam, string familienaam, string email, string wachtwoord, string stamNummer, bool el)
    {
        Voornaam = voornaam;
        Familienaam = familienaam;
        Email = email;
        Wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
        StamNummer = stamNummer;
        EersteLogin = el;
    }
}
```

GebruikerRepository:

```
public class GebruikerRepository : IGebruikerRepository
{
    private BachelorproefContext context;
    private DbSet<Gebruiker> gebruikers;

    public GebruikerRepository(BachelorproefContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        gebruikers = context.Gebruikers;
    }
    /*
    public void Add(Gebruiker gebruiker)
    {
        gebruikers.Add(gebruiker);
    }

    public void Delete(Gebruiker gebruiker)
    {
        gebruikers.Remove(gebruiker);
    }
    */
    public Gebruiker Findby(string stamNummer)
    {
        return gebruikers.SingleOrDefault(g => g.StamNummer == stamNummer);
    }
    public IQueryable<Gebruiker> FindAll()
    {
        return gebruikers.Include("Gebruiker").OrderBy(b => b.Familienaam);
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I constantly get the above said exception error at the method FindBy in the last class... I have examples of exercises from my classes in college and they're just like these, the ONLY thing changed is that in the lessons we worked with SQL server and now i'm supposed to work with a generated MySql Database.

Webconfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Bachelorproef" connectionString="Server=localhost;port=3306;Database=Bachelorproef;Uid=root;Pwd=root;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /></connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Could u guys please help me? I've been stuck for countless hours blindly staring at it without any use and i'm tired of it... I can connect to the DB using MySql Workbench 6.0, logging in using "root" & "root" but then i don't see any Tables or any data.

I'm a major noob in .net and for college we're thrown into the lion's den with this project and it's dreadfull... So please, coding wizards out there, could u help me :)?

Many thanks

D.B. aka Jepix

Comment: Skype and other stuff is also OK if it would/could be easier.